# Warning--I didn't find a database entry for

Tags: bibliographies

I have a huge bibliography but I'm having some trouble with some references that appear as "?" in my text and I always have this warning. Does someone know how I can correct this?

I cite using `\cite{}` as I do with the other references and they are in my `.bib` as are the others.

> ```
> Illegal end of database file---line 1833 of file ../references/Mybib.bib : } :
>  I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
> Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "horn2003gpcrdb"
> Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "mombaerts1996molecular"
> ```

Comment: There's not enough information here to give any precise answers, and since your bibliography is huge, you won't be able to post it here.  However, the warnings you show give clues to what you should look for.  Look to see what might be causing the "illegal end" at line 1833.  And look for the entries that "can't be found".  If you can't figure out what might be wrong with them -- or with the entries that precede them -- you might post just those few entries here, so that more eyes can examine them.

Comment: Do you have an unescaped % sign in a reference - maybe in an abstract field? All % need to be written as \%.

Comment: Other characters that might need to be escaped in the same way include `_`, `&` and `$` (and `@`, maybe). A missing or extra `{` or `}` also causes problems. And a missing `,`.